# How to make an app running node.js with express using pug template engine render comments?

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I've got a node.js app using Express framework and pug template engine. Locally, the same app renders comments in the html as per this documentation: https://pugjs.org/language/comments.html

My markup looks like this:

```html
html
  head
    // Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics
    script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-00000000-0"
    script.
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
      gtag('js', new Date());
      gtag('config', 'UA-00000000-0');
```

Which renders this in a local development environment:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
  <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-0000000-0"></script>
  <script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

    function gtag() {
      dataLayer.push(arguments);
    }
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'UA-0000000-0');
  </script>
```

But renders this on a production environment:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-00000000-0"></script>
  <script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

    function gtag() {
      dataLayer.push(arguments);
    }
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'UA-0000000-0');
  </script>
```

Leaving the comment out. The result is the same when the GA script is "included" from a html file.

Somewhere down the line, either pug or express are stripping out comments in a production environment. How do I add comments in this situation?

Comment: Just FYI google analytics is working, but I am still wondering why the comment is omitted from the final output.

Comment: Show your express setup, since I just tested a pug template with `NODE_ENV=production` and comments are not removed.